# Unicode Characters in htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, unicode, url-rewriting

Iam Using URL Re Write in .htacces File. Below is The Exact code. its Working Fine. But While i pass Unicode characters in arguments [ie: mypage.php?id=2&ampname=தமிழ்]. it shows some code like '%25E0%25AE%25A8%25E0%25AE%2' and Result is Page Not Found 404. Can anybody Solve this issue?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /mypage\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9+]+)/?$ mypage.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That code is probably the characters' unicode values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the URI is used to match against a rewrite rule's regex pattern, it is first *decoded*, so those `%` and hex values get turned into unicode. Your regex pattern `[A-Za-z0-9-]+` won't match unicode. Try changing your second rule so that it matches anything that isn't `/` instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /mypage\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ mypage.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```